# Smithing - How do I improve an item?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just made a whole set of Glass Armor (for my archer), and once I sit on the grindstone my armor does not show, only the iron daggers I am making to level smithing.

Am I missing something here?

Also, as an archer my goal is to make the Dragon set, right? I mean, is it better than the Nightingale set from Thiefs Guild questline? (I am doing this questline now, but I´ve never seen this set or the Dragon set, that's why I am asking.)

Comment: The nightingale armor and ancient shrouded has some of the highest base armor for light armor.  Not that it matters in the long run, with enough smithing skills, perks, and buffs, you can probably hit the cap with a basic set of leather armor.

Comment: You can, as long as you are willing to put the time into enchanting or alchemy, and it will still take a decent amount of money if you don't want to waste all the perks.

Comment: Is there any Cap ?
Hm...interesting,i missed that information.
I will just finish improving my glass armor set than :)

Comment: @MarcelloGrechiLins There is a cap of 80% damage reduction, which you reach with 567 displayed armor rating plus 100 "hidden" (basically just +20 each for wearing a helmet, boots, gauntlets and +40 for armor). Fully upgraded Glass equipment won't get you there, though, at least not without some Fortify Smithing, which you could use to make _Steel_ equipment reach the AR cap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Weapons are improved at the grindstone.

Armor is improved at the workbench.

Answer (score 2):

I just want to point out that, for your archer, your "goal" is not necessarily to achieve the highest AR. If you're going to avoid close-range combat almost exclusively, I'd focus on taking any mismatched Light Armor based on the enchantments they have when you discover them. You'll achieve a decent AR anyways, and chances are you'll pick up some "Bows do X more damage" enchants (or something equally useful).